# JetBrains IntelliJ / WebStorm : Is it possible to link css files as libraries to allow autocompletion for CSS class names from HTML?

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass, webpack, webstorm

In previous projects, I got used to have IntelliJ autocomplete CSS class names from the HTML editor.

For example, typing :

```
<table class="tab...">
```

Then `ctrl+space` would suggest classes from libraries (Bootstrap, Font-Awesome,...) or my own stylesheets, such as in this case `table`, `table-bordered`, etc.

But for it to work, the CSS file containing the classes must be linked using a `<stylesheet>` tag in the head section of the HTML file.

However, with more modern workflows, using preprocessors and build tools (In my case, I use bootstrap-sass and Webpack), it is not so explicit which CSS file will be included. I suppose that is is not realistic to expect the IDE to understand every possible way a CSS file can be processed and included in a HTML file.

**Is there a way to explicitly specify CSS (SCSS, LESS,...) files, at the IDE level, to be included for autocompletion ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In HTML files with root `<html>` element (i.e. not partials) only those selectors that are  defined in stylesheets explicitly linked to the page using `<link>` tag are available in completion.
We have feature requests for adding intellisense for selectors that aren't explicitly linked - [WEB-17009](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17009), [WEB-24264](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24264). Please feel free to vote for them